# Splitting array into multiple arrays/bins

Tags: excel, vba

I have an array of strings - call it Xarray. I have three other arrays of strings - Aarray, Barray, and Carray. Xarray may have a small length - say 3 or 4. A, B, and C arrays are usually a longer master list (say 10+ elements each).

Xarray only contains elements that are found in Aarray, Barray, or Carray.

I need to split Xarray into 3 bins/arrays - call them XA, XB and XC. XA should only contain entries from Xarray that are found in Aarray. XB should only contain entries from Xarray that are found in Barray. XC should... you get the picture.

What is a good way to do this? Appreciate your help.

Comment: May I ask about your attempts to solve your problem? We would be much more of a help if you give us something to chew on.

Comment: Romcel, I considered looping through Xarray and matching to each of the master arrays, but was hoping for something more on the lines of "ismember" that you can apply to sets or matrices or arrays. I am not fluent in VBA and get by with a mish-mash of trial/error, reading help, scouring the web, etc. Please note that I am not a programmer or IT person, and that using this type of code is not central to my work. It's just that in some instances if I wrote some custom code, it'd get easier to deal with some repetitive aspects. My mind is now a jumble of what can be done in different frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your string arrays are one dimensional, would something like this work?

```
Sub ArraySlicing()

    Dim Xarray() As String
    Dim Aarray() As String, Barray() As String, Carray() As String
    Dim XA() As String, XB() As String, XC() As String
    Dim XA_RwIndexList As String, XB_RwIndexList As String, XC_RwIndexlist As String
    Dim i As Long

    'create test data arrays
    Xarray = Split("Red,Blue,Green,Yellow,Orange,Lime,Purple,Turquoise,Pink,Brown,White,Black,Gold", ",")
    Aarray = Split("Apple,Orange,Banana,Lime,Pear,Orange,Green Apple,Red Apple", ",")
    Barray = Split("Pink Rose,Tulip,Daisy,Bluebell,Carnation,Marigold", ",")
    Carray = Split("redwood,spruce,lime,pine,oak,lemon,chestnut,walnut,orange", ",")

    'loop XArray and check for matches
    For i = LBound(Xarray) To UBound(Xarray)

        'note application.match is case insensitive and will only match complete words
        'i.e. "orange" & "Orange" will be found, "Pink Rose" will not

        If Not IsError(Application.Match(Xarray(i), Aarray, 0)) Then _
        XA_RwIndexList = XA_RwIndexList & "_" & i 'index matching rows

        If Not IsError(Application.Match(Xarray(i), Barray, 0)) Then _
        XB_RwIndexList = XB_RwIndexList & "_" & i 'index matching rows

        If Not IsError(Application.Match(Xarray(i), Carray, 0)) Then _
        XC_RwIndexlist = XC_RwIndexlist & "_" & i 'index matching rows

    Next i

    'check if XA_RwIndexList was initialized i.e. there were matches
    If Not XA_RwIndexList = vbNullString Then

        'trim preceeding "_" & store row #s in XA array
        XA = Split(Mid(XA_RwIndexList, 2), "_")

        'loop XA and replace row # with corresponding values from XArray
        For i = LBound(XA) To UBound(XA)
            XA(i) = Xarray(XA(i))
        Next i

    End If

    'check if XB_RwIndexList was initialized i.e. there were matches
    If Not XB_RwIndexList = vbNullString Then

        'trim preceeding "_" & store row #s in XB array
        XB = Split(Mid(XB_RwIndexList, 2), "_")

        'loop XB and replace row # with corresponding values from XArray
        For i = LBound(XB) To UBound(XB)

            XB(i) = Xarray(XB(i))

        Next i

    End If

    'check if XC_RwIndexList was initialized i.e. there were matches
    If Not XC_RwIndexlist = vbNullString Then

        'trim preceeding "_" & store row #s in XC array
        XC = Split(Mid(XC_RwIndexlist, 2), "_")

        'loop XC and replace row # with corresponding values from XArray
        For i = LBound(XC) To UBound(XC)

            XC(i) = Xarray(XC(i))

        Next i

    End If

End Sub
```

Depending on your string matching requirements `Application.Match` may not be the best fit, but thought I'd suggest it as it's a good way to avoid needing to also loop the other 3 arrays.

Comment: Thank you very much thatandyward. I am aware that I could loop through Xarray elements and figure out where it belongs. I was hoping to find a more direct way (something like "ismember" that you can apply to arrays directly). Nevertheless, this looks like it should work. I greatly appreciate your taking the time to write down something this nicely.

Comment: The built-in array handling in VBA is pretty basic, you normally have to roll your own methods for anything more 'advanced'. I find [this site](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Arrays_en.html) pretty helpful for dealing with arrays, has lots of clever tricks.